# Why does the else run in this if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if (finalDistance > 10) {
    dmgMulti = dmgMulti;
}

if (finalDistance < 1) {
    dmgMulti = dmgMulti + 0.5;
}

else {
    dmgMulti = dmgMulti + (0.5/finalDistance);
}
```

Even when finalDistance = something like 20 it still runs, is there something I'm doing horribly wrong?

Comment: The 2nd `if` should be `else if`. Makes sense, no?

Comment: Thanks this worked, how do I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` only applies to the second `if`. Since 20 is not less than 1, the `else` branch is executed. If you want strictly one of the conditions to be entered, the second `if` should be replaced with an `else if`:

```
if (finalDistance > 10) {
    dmgMulti = dmgMulti;
}
else if (finalDistance < 1) { // Here!
    dmgMulti = dmgMulti + 0.5;
}
else {
    dmgMulti = dmgMulti + (0.5/finalDistance);
}
```